# Turn \r\n to a new list item in Android

Tags: java, android, parsing, html-parsing

I'm currently being handed a string such as `Hello there my\r\nName is\r\nJohn Smith\r\nand\r\nstuff` and I want to put each line in a new list item... such as:

### Desired Result (List view with separate list items):

```
Hello there my
--------------
Name is
--------------
John Smith
--------------
and
--------------
stuff
```

I figured I would be able to parse the entire string by the `\r\n` to put each line into an array and use an array adapter to set the list view, but it just interprets the \r\n as a new line. So I end up having a text view that looks like this:

### Current result (Just one textView):

```
Hello there my
Name is
John Smith
and
stuff
```

Is there any way to stop it \r\n from just creating a new line so that I can parse it into an array?

```
String[] myText = {"Helo there my", "Name is", "John Smith", "and", "stuff"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
String[] myText = originalText.split("\r\n");
```

Comment: Ah. I guess I was just over thinking it. Thank you so much. I didn't think it would split because of how `\r\n` works. Thank you so much. I thought this was gonna involve some crazy html parsing. Thanks!

Comment: @EGHDK Yeah, that happens some times, go and have a rest, or much better go to sleep a bit ;-)